# Incrementing a value from another .java file

Tags: java, android

This is 'CatList_Activity.java' file

```
    public class CatList_Activity extends ActionBarActivity{
GridView grid;
private String[] arrImagesStrings;
String Foldername;
CatListAdapter adapter;
private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.catlist_activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.lsv_catlist);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    Foldername=i.getStringExtra("Folder");

    arrImagesStrings = listAssetFiles(Foldername);  
    adapter=new CatListAdapter(CatList_Activity.this, R.layout.catlist_item, arrImagesStrings, Foldername);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.e("name", ""+Foldername+"/"+arrImagesStrings[position]);
            Intent intentdraw=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Draw_Activity.class);
            intentdraw.putExtra("Folder", Foldername+"/"+arrImagesStrings[position]);
            startActivity(intentdraw);

        }
```

What I want to do is to increment 'position' value while being in another file (called Draw_Activity.java), so that when I click on a button in that file, I go to the next page, basically make position value position + 1. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Make incremental field static.

Comment: you mean position variable defined in OnItemClick method ?

Comment: Whatever you are doing, I am sure is not the right architecture. Why do you need to increment `position` variable which is inside a callback method?

Comment: you can do this by setting the variable to `SharedPreference` or declaring this variable as `static` in same activity..

Comment: @Ronik5k2 basically I'm making a drawing app and the file 'CatList_Activity.java' is the menu where the list of images is stored. When clicking on one, it goes to 'Draw_Activity.java', opening the image (id being the 'position'). I want to make the 'next' button, to go to the next image (without returning to 'CatList_Activity.java'), and I am guessing by incrementing 'position' value I will achieve that, but I might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Draw_Activity object make a public function to increase or do what do you want.

```
public class Draw_Activity ... {
    public void increasePosition(){
        this.position++;
    }
}
```

If from this class "CatList_Activity" you cant access "Draw_Activity", you can make a static class to retrive the instance of the other object.

```
public class Draw_Activity ... {

    //private instance
    private Draw_Activity instance;
    //constructor, if this is a static method you can access it whithout this
    //doing this Draw_Activity.increasePosition();
    public Draw_Activity {
       ...
       instance = this;
    }

    //public method to retrive this object
    public static Draw_Activity getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And now from your class "CatList_Activity" you can do this:

```
public class CatList_Activity extends ActionBarActivity{
....
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Draw_Activity.getInstance().increasePosition();
    }
}
```

I dont know if you mean to do this, or if this applies to your problem. Hope it helps u.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value if position using intents like

```
intentdraw.putExtra("position", position);
```

define global variable `position` in `Draw_Activity`

```
int position;
```

and retrieve this value in your next activity `Draw_Activity`'s `onCreate(...)` method where you want to increment the position counter like this

```
onCreate(..) {
    setContentView...;
    position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position") + 1;
}
```

send this variable on next activity on button click listener..